# Laravel "Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)" when fileinfo extension is enabled

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, symfony, mime-types

So on my windows PC when I upload files with Laravel, everything works perfectly, but when on my Linux shared host, `php_fileinfo` error is thrown. I have checked and made sure that `php_fileinfo` is enabled in PHP Extensions Selector. Fellow programmers, I'm on my wit's end.

Answer (score 1):

You should enable the following line in your php.ini and then restart your apache

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Enabling mean just uncomment the line in your php.ini file

i.e., From this `;extension=php_fileinfo.dll` to `extension=php_fileinfo.dll`

Comment: I already did this on windows machine, but on a Linux shared hosting, php.ini file is not visible for editing for security reasons and it's on my shared hosting that I'm having the issue.

Comment: Have you installed this extension?

Comment: did you figure this out @user1867071?